# SASS: Compressing code - don't compress certain lines

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, codekit

I have a scss file within a Wordpress set up that I'm compressing, at the top of the stylesheet is all the theme information, when the file gets compiled I lose all this information.

Is there a way I can keep that part of the file intact then compress the rest of it?

Essentially it's a comment which gets stripped out in the compressed file:

```
/* Theme Name: Minimal
Description: Minimal theme
Author: Xxx
Author URI: Xxx
Version: 1.0
Version:1.0.0 */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting (`!`) comments in your `.scss` file like:

```
/*! Theme Name: Minimal
Description: Minimal theme
Author: Xxx
Author URI: Xxx
Version: 1.0
Version:1.0.0 */
```

Then compile.